# Using custom jQuery radio buttons with CakePHP Form Helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, cakephp, checkbox

I'm using a custom jQuery plugin to convert radio buttons to actual images, and it works with basic checkboxes, but when using Cake's built-in input form helper, it acts more as a checkbox by not unchecking the already clicked options. Not only that, but it isn't populating $this->data (or sending anything when the form is submitted).

The js looks like this:

```
//##############################
// jQuery Custom Radio-buttons and Checkbox; basically it's styling/theming for Checkbox and Radiobutton elements in forms
// By Dharmavirsinh Jhala - dharmavir@gmail.com
// Date of Release: 13th March 10
// Version: 0.8
/*
 USAGE:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(":radio").behaveLikeCheckbox();
    }
*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bananas").dgStyle();
var elmHeight = "15";   // should be specified based on image size

// Extend JQuery Functionality For Custom Radio Button Functionality
jQuery.fn.extend({
    dgStyle: function()
    {
        // Initialize with initial load time control state
        $.each($(this), function(){
            var elm = $(this).children().get(0);
            elmType = $(elm).attr("type");
            $(this).data('type',elmType);
            $(this).data('checked',$(elm).attr("checked"));
            $(this).dgClear();
        });
        $(this).mouseup(function() {
            $(this).dgHandle();
        });
    },
    dgClear: function()
    {
        if($(this).data("checked") == true)
        {
            $(this).addClass("checked");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).removeClass("checked");
        }
    },
    dgHandle: function()
    {
        var elm =   $(this).children().get(0);
        if($(this).data("checked") == true)
            $(elm).dgUncheck(this);
        else
            $(elm).dgCheck(this);

        if($(this).data('type') == 'radio')
        {
            $.each($("input[name='"+$(elm).attr("name")+"']"),function()
            {
                if(elm!=this)
                    $(this).dgUncheck(-1);
            });
        }
    },
    dgCheck: function(div)
    {
        $(this).attr("checked",true);
        $(div).data('checked',true).addClass('checked');
    },
    dgUncheck: function(div)
    {
        $(this).attr("checked",false);
        if(div != -1)
            $(div).data('checked',false).css({
                backgroundPosition:"center 0"
            });
        else
            $(this).parent().data("checked",false).removeClass("checked");
    }
});
```

The PHP/Html looks like this:

```
<span id="bananas-cat" class="cat">
    <?= $this->Form->radio('bananas',array(),array('legend' => false, 'id' => 'bananas', 'name' => 'category')); ?>
    <label for="bananas">Bananas</label>
</span>
```

While it upon first inspection may look correct, when clicked, nothing gets passed within $this->data and it acts like a checkbox and doesn't unselect the value when I add an additional radio checkbox.

Although the radio functionality does work without CakePHP's html form helper like so:

```
<span id="animals-cat" class="cat">
    <input type="radio" name="category" id="animals" />
    <label for="animals">Animals</label>
</span>
```

If anyone can help me out here, I would be forever indebted. I've been trying to solve this for way too long now that I'm considering just scrapping the whole idea to begin with.

Comment: Post the HTML output from the `$this->Form->radio` call as well. You don't need to use the Form helper for everything - create the radio buttons manually, name the fields using cake convention `data[Model][field]` and use your custom JS - job done.

Comment: Something similar happen to me, the problem was that names in cakephp convention has [] and those need to be escaped for the `input[name='"+$(elm).attr("name")+"']`part, hope this works for you to

Comment: @Ross I tried reverting to the normal method and putting `data[Submission][category]` in the name field, but when it posts data, it looks like `category => on`. Not sure where that 'on' is coming from.

Comment: @api55 What exactly did you escape? Can you please share an example?

Comment: sure, i escaped the [] characters, in the end you will have something like this `"$(input[@name='data\\[Model\\]\\[radioName\\]']:radio").change` yep, a bunch of slashes, but without it it doesn't work

Comment: @api55 are you using the js file that I posted above? In mine, the line is: `$.each($("input[name='"+$(elm).attr("name")+"']")`. I tried to implement yours into it, but it didn't seem to work. Any suggestion?

Comment: i haven't used your JS, im use an example of what i did. maybe you should something like this str1 = $(elm).attr("name"); str1 = str1.replace ("[", "\\["); str1 = str1.replace ("]", "\\]"); and use str1 instead

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is see and compare the HTML output of example and one being generated by CakPHP, try to make it similar to example so that you can get your custom-radio-buttons working.

But if you can not do that I would highly recommend to override those helpers by some parameters so that you can get the exact HTML as an output and Javascript should work flawlessly.

Let me know if that does not work for you.